# Can't get callbacks in ngx-fullpage to work

Tags: angular, fullpage.js

Has anyone used callbacks in ngx-fullpage (https://github.com/meiblorn/ngx-fullpage) in an Angular2 app?

Comment: Have you tried asking on their github issues forum?

Comment: Yeah but no answer. I gave up and did a workaround using ng-animations.